# Could not init a PFObject subclass

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

After upgrading to Xcode 6.3 6D570 (and Swift 1.2), the init of a subclassed object does not compile. 
Let's say I have a class called Armor, which inherits from PFObject, PFSubclassing (exactly as Parse documentation says).

When I try to create an instance, like `var armor = Armor()`, I get the following compile error:

> Missing argument for parameter 'className' in call

Then I read in Parse docs that I should use the 'object' class method to init a subclassed object. So I tried to init like this: `var armor = Armor.object()`.

But then I get the following compile error:

> 'object()' is unavailable: use object construction 'PFObject()'

I'm using Parse SDK version 1.7.1.

I also override the `parseClassName` method as follows:

```
class func parseClassName() -> String {
    return "Armor"
}
```

I registered the subclass inside the initialise method and on app delegate before I setup Parse:

```
override class func initialize() {
    var onceToken : dispatch_once_t = 0;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken) {
        self.registerSubclass()
    }
}
```

How should I properly init a subclassed object?

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to include the compile error. What exactly is failing?

Comment: My mistake, added the compile error, thanks.

Comment: Have you updated your Parse SDK to version 1.7.1?

Comment: Did you override the `parseClassName` method in the subclass?  If so, can you show it?

Comment: Did you call `Armor.registerSubclass()`? (or `self.registerSubclass()` inside of  `Armor`'s `class func initialize()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

=========================================================================

THIS HAS BEEN FIXED IN 1.7.3 PARSE SDK
You can download the new version here:
https://parse.com/docs/downloads

=========================================================================

Though docs are not clear on that, using `.object()` in Swift is not required anymore.
as said [here](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/349654705211582/?comment_id=759467350754965) and in the Swift code snippet found [here](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#subclasses/iOS)

Now, this is **weird** but to make `Armor()` work you need to reference `PFUser` class somehow in the same file. Maybe it doesn't have to be `PFUser` but I havent dug deeper into it.

So, this won't work

```
import UIKit
import Parse
import Bolts

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        Parse.setApplicationId("appID", clientKey: "clientKey")

        let myArmor = Armor()

        return true
    }
}
```

But this will

```
import UIKit
import Parse
import Bolts

private let fix = PFUser.hash() // here's the weird trick

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        Parse.setApplicationId("appID", clientKey: "clientKey")

        let myArmor = Armor()

        return true
    }
}
```

Hope this helps and `Parse` pushes a fix out soon.

Also [reported as a bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1647055045527392/)

Answer (score 0):

register the class as a subclass in the `AppDelegate`, but before `Parse.initialize` is called.
Then you can `delete` the `overwritten function initialize`

This would make:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]!) -> Bool {

        Armor.registerSubclass()

        // Further initialization

        return true
    }
```

then just initialize the class by calling the constructor:

```
var myArmor = Armor()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it but it didn't work. I remind that I get a compilation error, before I build the app, so it shouldn't be affected by changes in methods that are not directly related.

Comment: @Alonzo have you tried deleting the derived Data? and cleaning the project?

Comment: Yes & yes. BTW, when I use the constructor advised by the compiler: `var myArmor = Armor(className: "Armor") `, it works well (but it's not a clean solution)

Comment: yeah I even tried to override init() and that didn't work either